# vb.net: override toString method for enums

Tags: vb.net, enums, tostring, enumeration

I would like to override toString method for each enum value. For example, I know in Java it can be done as below:

```
public enum Language_Culture_Names{

  English {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "en-GB";
    }
  },
  Spanish {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "es-ES";
    }
  },
  Catalan {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "ca-ES";
    }
  }

}

  System.out.println(Language_Culture_Names.English); -> returns en-GB
  System.out.println(Language_Culture_Names.Spanish); -> returns es-ES
  System.out.println(Language_Culture_Names.Catalan); -> returns ca-ES
```

So how to do this in VB.NET?

Comment: instead of adding a "solution" part, add it as an answer. It is most valid to answer your own questions. My suggestion here would be to rollback your latest edit and add that part as an answer instead.

Comment: @Default I agree. Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should use a `Class` customized for yourself, since `Enums` are numeric constants and not string constants.

However, if you must use `Enum` and are looking for a generic solution, this is how I would do it:

First, add a `Module` to your project, with the following code:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Module1
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function ToString2(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
        Dim fi As Reflection.FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
        Dim aattr() As DescriptionAttribute = DirectCast(fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())
        If aattr.Length > 0 Then
            Return aattr(0).Description
        Else
            Return EnumConstant.ToString()
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

We name our function `ToString2` because `Enum.ToString` already exists, and can't be overridden. You can name it anything else.

Now in your class where the `Enum` is declared, decorate the Enum Members with `Description` attribute:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel  '<-- be sure to include this Namespace

Public Enum Language_Culture_Names
    <Description("en-GB")> English = 1
    <Description("es-ES")> Spanish = 2
    <Description("ca-ES")> Catalan = 3
End Enum
```

And finally dump the `Enum.ToString` method and use our new `Enum.ToString2` method instead.

e.g.

```
TextBox1.Text = Language_Culture_Names.English.ToString2()
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have used type-safe-enum Pattern as below:

```
Public NotInheritable Class LanguageCultureNames

    Private ReadOnly name As String
    Private ReadOnly value As Integer

    Public Shared ReadOnly English As New LanguageCultureNames(0, "en-GB")
    Public Shared ReadOnly Spanish As New LanguageCultureNames(1, "es-ES")
    Public Shared ReadOnly Catalan As New LanguageCultureNames(2, "ca-ES")

    Private Sub New(ByVal value As Integer, ByVal name As String)
        Me.name = name
        Me.value = value
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return name
    End Function

End Class
```